# How to apply CSS style if the p element does not have a ul

Tags: html, css

I want to apply the `page-break-inside:avoid` property to all `p` elements that do not have a `ul` element.

```css
p {
    margin-top: 4pt !important;
    margin-bottom:6pt !important;
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    orphans: 4;
    widows: 2;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello text </p>
   <p>hello <ul>
    <li>list </li>
   </ul>
```

I want to exclude the second paragraph. Is it possible through CSS? I am looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: No, it is not possible to exclude `p` elements with `ul` elements within them.

Comment: Semi irrelevant anyway since p tags can't contain ul tags. Invalid HTML Any decent browser would render that as `<p>...</p><p>...</p><ul>...`

Comment: `p` element cannot contain `ul`

Comment: Thanks. I use this mainly for print and no errors were shown. A good lesson. By the way, in general, I did search for an answer for many days.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `ul` inside a `p` element. As for the identifier topic, the only option for this would be to use the `:has` pseudo class, but it's [still not compatible](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas).

You can check its documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

Revise your code to improve the structure.

What you could do is something like this:

```html
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<ul>
   <li>Element 1</li>
   <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph</p>
```

This way if you want to affect a `ul` that's right after a `p` you could use this selector:

```css
p ~ ul {
   color: red;
}
//Selects every <ul> element that are preceded by a <p> element
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid. p elements can only contain phrasing content https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element